# Application does not stop after AWSIotMqttClient disconnected

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I'm working with AWSIotMqttClient to subscribe and publish to topics. After I received all messages I want to stop my application. But it works infinitely long. Here a simple code which works infinitely, even without subscribes:

```
 SampleUtil.KeyStorePasswordPair keyStorePasswordPair =
                SampleUtil.getKeyStorePasswordPair("certificate.pem", "privateKey.pem");

        AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(
                "mqtt-broker.address",
                "deviceID",
                keyStorePasswordPair.keyStore,
                keyStorePasswordPair.keyPassword);

        client.connect();
        client.disconnect();
```

Here is my logs:

```
    > Task :Application.main()
Cert file:certificate.pem Private key: privateKey.pem
????. 20, 2019 11:56:45 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionSuccess
INFO: Connection successfully established
????. 20, 2019 11:56:45 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient onConnectionSuccess
INFO: Client connection active: 5dcd561596c30e0001e4b5d5

????. 20, 2019 11:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionClosed
INFO: Connection permanently closed
????. 20, 2019 11:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient onConnectionClosed
INFO: Client connection closed: 5dcd561596c30e0001e4b5d5
```

I can stop my application with System.exit(0) but it is undesirable for me. I expect that after all code is passed, the application will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/issues/69) . Updating aws-iot-device-sdk to 1.3.4 version

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-iot-device-sdk-java:1.3.4'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-iot-device-sdk-java-samples:1.3.4'
```

resolved the problem.